# Testing for matching shapefile pair then processing pair Arcpy

Tags: arcpy

just looking for some help to solve a logic issue (very inexperienced with python/programming).

The task I have is to check two different folders for a matching pair of shapefiles where the strings would match up to the first "_". The inherit problem with this was that some shapefiles would be missing their counterpart and I only want to process if both exist. The only way I could figure out how to make matching pairs was to rename the shapefile with a split and store in a feature list then test for the match.

The problem with my solution is that sometimes the script will need to be re-run on the shapefiles, so I don't really want to rename the data or have to back it up before each run manually (it is part of a statistical cleaning and regression model for the data, sometimes the data needs to be scaled after the fact or additional sources are added).

How do I do this without renaming the shapefiles?

```
import arcpy, os, numpy, datetime
from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput=True

harvest = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
applied = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

#Create or clean the working gdb 
if arcpy.Exists(os.path.join(output, "cleaning.gdb")):  
    arcpy.Delete_management(os.path.join(output, "cleaning.gdb"))
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(output, "cleaning.gdb")
else:
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(output, "cleaning.gdb")

#save current time
now = datetime.datetime.now()

#Create applied feature list and rename shapefiles 
env.workspace = applied
fcs2 = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print("Renaming As Applied Data")
for fc in fcs2:
    fn = fc.rsplit('_',3)[0]
    print(fn)
    fc.replace(fc, fn)
    arcpy.Rename_management(fc, fn)
fcs2 = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

#Create harvest feature list and rename shapefiles
env.workspace = harvest
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print("Renaming Data")
for fc in fcs:
    fn = fc.rsplit('_',3)[0]
    print(fn)
    fc.replace(fc, fn)
    arcpy.Rename_management(fc, fn)
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

env.workspace = r"path"

#Test to make sure we can match!
print("Checking for matching datasets!")
count = 0
for fc in fcs:
    if fc in fcs2:
        #if there is both data for a field we will clean!
        #set variables first for file paths
        adata = os.path.join(applied, fc)
        hdata = os.path.join(harvest, fc)
        outputtable = os.path.join(output, fc.rsplit('.',1)[0] + ".xls")
        print("> We have a match!")
        print("> " + fc)
 ##run method etc
```

Comment: I don't see that this is GIS-related. While you may be using some arcpy tools to get the list of files you want, ultimately, you're comparing files in folders which should probably be asked on [so].